# Resource Router for Markets

Tags: resource-router

I'm building a site that has 20 city markets using a Markets Channel. Each market will have it's own version of a page, so austin/store, nyc/store, austin/about, nyc/about, etc.

I also have a National market that is the catch all version of a page that does not have a market in the first segment, so /store, /about, etc.

The thing is that if we're using the National market channel to display a page I don't want that segment in the URL. It should not be national/store, national/about. A visitor should never see a market in the URL unless it's on a proper market like austin or nyc.

My question is, can I use resource router to accomplish something like this and how would I go about setting it up so I don't have to create two versions of a route, one for national and one for proper markets? And then on top of that only displaying segment_1 if it's a market besides national.

Comment: I guess what I'm thinking in using Resource Router is checking segment_1 if it's a valid URL Title for a Market Channel Entry. If it is then set a global using the URL Title of the Market. If not then set a market global to "national".

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how Resource Router can do this, but I *can* tell you how standard Template Routes can do this.

Make templates or template groups for `/store`, `/about`, etc. (Doesn't really matter where they are or what they're named, since you'll be adding routes to them anyway.)

Then add a route for each of those templates like so:

`store/{market:alpha}`

`about/market:alpha}`

Etc.

Leave *Segments Required* set to "No".

Then in your template, use the `channel:entries` tag like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="markets" {if segment:market}url_title="{segment:market}"{if:else}url_title="national"{/if} dynamic="no" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
```

Does that do the trick?